# how to assign json object to the datatable?

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

By the query I fectched the data assigned to the object by setter methods and added each object to the list how to put it to the datatable

here is my java code

```
try {
    ps=cn.prepareStatement(" select month_year,count(*),sum(booking_amount),count(distinct user_id) from DAILYBOOKINGREPORT2 where yearr=? group by month_year order by MONTH_YEAR DESC");
    ps.setString(1,y);
    rs=ps.executeQuery();   
    while(rs.next())   
    {  
        String month_year="";
        int no_of_tickets=0,no_of_agents=0;
        float booking_amount=0;  
        int perDay_tickets=0;
        String s="";
        month_year=rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println(month_year);
        no_of_tickets=rs.getInt(2);
        booking_amount=rs.getFloat(3);
        no_of_agents=rs.getInt(4); 
        s= month_year.substring(4,6);
        int last_num=Integer.parseInt(s);

        if(last_num%2==0)
        {
            perDay_tickets= no_of_tickets/30;
        }    
        else{ 
            perDay_tickets= no_of_tickets/31;
        }

        MonthlyBeans obj=new MonthlyBeans();  
        // System.out.println("no of tickets"+no_of_tickets);
        // System.out.println("perday"+perDay_tickets); 
        float avg_pricing=booking_amount/ no_of_tickets;
        int per_agent=no_of_tickets/ no_of_agents;
        //System.out.println("avg"+avg_pricing); 
        //System.out.println("per agent"+per_agent);  
        obj.setMonth(month_year);  
        obj.setUnique_users( no_of_agents);
        obj.setNo_of_tickets(no_of_tickets);
        obj.setBooking_amount(booking_amount);
        obj.setPerAgent(per_agent);
        obj.setPerday(perDay_tickets);
        obj.setAvg_pricing(avg_pricing); 
        list.add(obj); 
    }    
    result = gson.toJson(list);  
}
```

my json object looks like this

```
Object
    No_of_tickets:  253
    avg_pricing  :1034.0747
    booking_amount:261620.89
    month:"201405"
    perday:15
    perAgent:16
    unique_users:15
```

here is my html

```
<table class="table-striped table-bordered" id="tblData"">
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <th>month</th>
            <th>No_of_tickets</th>
            <th>booking_amount</th>
            <th>avg_pricing</th>
            <th>unique_users</th>
            <th>perday</th>
            <th>perAgent</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

here is my javascript

```
$.ajax({       
    url:"Monthly_report",
    data:"&t4="+ $("#slc").val(),
    dataType:"json",
    type:"get",                      
    success:function(response){
    console.log(response); 
    $('#tblData').dataTable({
        data : response,
        columns : [  {  'response' : 'response.month' },
            {  'response' : 'response.No_of_tickets' },
            {  'response' : 'response.booking_amount' },
            {  'response' : 'response.avg_pricing' },
            {  'response' : 'response.unique_users' },
            {  'response' : 'response.perday' }]
        }) ;
    }
});
```

please help me with this how can i assign that object data to  DATATABLE I am not able to do it `response.month` or `something else` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables bind columns with data. I suppose response is an array of your json object.
First time you can find some explanation in the [datatables docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data).

Second time you failing in binding your data. You search to bind your first column to the property **response.month**. But you want to bind it to **month**.

I purpose you this solution :

```
$('#tblData').dataTable({
    data : response,
    columns : [ 
        {'data' : "month" },
        {'data' : "No_of_tickets" },
        {'data' : "booking_amount" },
        {'data' : "avg_pricing" },
        {'data' : "unique_users" },
        {'data' : "perday" }
    ]
});
```

I hope this can help you.

**NB :** You can manage [ajax request with datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax). It will be useful if you want, sort, paginate or something else.

Comment: thank you it worked for me , but sending Ajax request on selection,for the first selection only it working for the second  selection its giving error  '   DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3'